# Do I need to add <script> tags to link to framework like jquery (cdn or locally hosted) if I installed it using the npm?

Tags: npm, package, npm-install, fullpage.js

If I install a package i.e.Fullpage.js using npm do I still need to include a `<link>` or `<script src="fullpage.js></script>` in my html document?

```
{
"name": "npm_packages",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "JQuery packages/frameworks to be used for project",
  "main": "script.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "fullpage.js": "^2.9.4",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1"
}
```

I am writing my JavaScript in the script.js file. I have not used the npm before and I can't find an answer anywhere. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

NPM is just a package manager. It helps you download the files you need. Nothing more. 
You still need to add the scripts in the HTML document.

Comment: Thanks! When I add the script can I link to the ones in the node_modules folder?

Comment: Thanks! When I add the script can I link to the ones in the node_modules folder?